# Display a WooCommerce Checkout Template only if Cart Contains a Category

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

We have a WooCommerce Multi-step checkout. One checkout step is for insurance, but this insurance is only for the rental category.

Looking to only show the insurance step if a rental product is in the cart. Found a great article on [Checking if the WooCommerce Cart Contains a Product Category](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/checking-woocommerce-cart-contains-product-category/) but the code is not giving the desired result when we place our add_action snippet to load the checkout step:

[image]

Here is our add_action call for the custom template (

```
add_action('woocommerce_multistep_checkout_after_shipping', 'add_my_insurance_step_with_new_field');
        function add_my_insurance_step_with_new_field( $checkout ) {
                wc_get_template( 'checkout/insurance.php', array( 'checkout' => $checkout ) );
            }
```

And here is it placed within the code from SkyVerge:

```
// set our flag to be false until we find a product in that category
$cat_check = false;

// check each cart item for our category
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    // replace 'membership' with your category's slug
    if ( has_term( 'rentals', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
        $cat_check = true;
        // break because we only need one "true" to matter here
        break;
    }
}

// if a product in the cart is in our category, do something
if ( $cat_check ) {
    // we have the category, do what we want
    add_action('woocommerce_multistep_checkout_after_shipping', 'add_my_insurance_step_with_new_field');
        function add_my_insurance_step_with_new_field( $checkout ) {
                wc_get_template( 'checkout/insurance.php', array( 'checkout' => $checkout ) );
            }
}
```

So very close! Not sure what could be going wrong.

Thanks for your help,
-L

Comment: I also found this excellent article on [How to Create Conditional Checkout Fields in WooCommerce](https://wordimpress.com/create-conditional-checkout-fields-woocommerce/).

Answer (score 1):

This did the fix. Set `$cat_check` to `false`, run through each product in the cart, check if it has our category slug (`rentals`) in the cart, if true we break out and run the next `if` statement.

Which gets the template file and loads it before checkout order info (`woocommerce_multistep_checkout_before_order_info`).

```
function cclever_show_insurance_step_if_rentals() {
    if ( function_exists( 'wc_checkout_add_ons' ) ) {
        // set to false first
        $cat_check = false;

        // check each cart item for our category
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

            $product = $cart_item['data'];

            // replace 'rentals' with your category's slug
            if ( has_term( 'rentals', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
                $cat_check = true;
                // we only need one "true" to leave
                break;
            }
        }

        // if a product in the cart is in our category, remove the add-ons
        if ( $cat_check ) {

            add_action('woocommerce_multistep_checkout_before_order_info', 'cclever_add_insurance_custom_step');
            function cclever_add_insurance_custom_step( $checkout ) {
              wc_get_template( 'checkout/insurance.php', array( 'checkout' => $checkout ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'cclever_show_insurance_step_if_rentals' );
```

Hope that helps someone out. ** or if there is anything wrong with my code, please let me know. Thanks!